# Create shortcut in fabric to connect with ADLS Gen2

Tags: microsoft-fabric

how to create a shortcut for ADLS Gen 2 but I am getting an invalid credentials error, however I am placing the correct key, any recommendations on security, or permissions I have to take into account to be able to create this shortcut??
thanks a lot for the advice

Comment: Does it have a private endpoint? Thats not support in Fabric at this time

Answer (score 0):

you can link your datalake into your fabric lakehouse as a shortcut .. then its easy for you to manage your data across Microsoft fabric.

1. Create Lakehouse following MS documentation tutorial:
2. Link your ADLS in Lakehouse: open lakehouse -> add new shortcut
   [image]
3. select ADLS Gen2 :

[image]

4. In Connection settings URL : copy the link in Data Lake Storage endpoints tab in your ADLS account in azure portal :
   open azure portal -> your ADLS account -> settings -> endpoints -> Data Lake Storage URL

[image]